# Postfix aliases

Tags: postfix, aliases

I have a question.
Is it possible to configure postfix aliases to retrieve them from an external script?

```
alias_maps = /path/to/pythons_script.py
```

or

```
alias_maps = /path/to/script.sh
```

**EDIT (based on autor's comments):**

Aliases should be sender dependent.

Comment: Do you want service queries about aliases by postfix in real time?

Comment: exactly, this postfix server won't send many emails. 
I need to do some extra thing when Postfix forward emails.

Answer (score 1):

You may configure postfix to query your python daemon about aliases using `socketmap` protocol.

http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#alias_database
http://www.postfix.org/DATABASE_README.html#types

There are a few implementation of socketmap daemons in python e.g. [pysrs](http://bmsi.com/python/milter.html).

Socket map protocol has beeb introduced by sendmail. It is very simple:
http://www.postfix.org/socketmap_table.5.html

---

Postfix also supports another protocol but it is postix specific:
http://www.postfix.org/tcp_table.5.html

Comment: tcp lookup method is great for me, but it doesn't matter because postfix gives only recipient email, I need also sender email. :(

Comment: Add additional requirements to your query after "**EDIT:**" line.  Aliases are not sender depended.

Comment: :( I think that I don't understand how I should it do

Comment: I have added it - it should be visible after review/moderation (You reputation score may be to low to do it yourself).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it is not possible. You can use mysql table instead and insert data into mysql with your own script

Answer (score 0):

Postfix knows a lot of lookup tables: http://www.postfix.org/DATABASE_README.html

But a lookup tables like exec:/path/scriptname isn't between them, although it weren't too hard to develop one. In your place I generated a text table with the script and called then 'postmap' for it.